# increase ECS task definition override character limit 8192

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Working with ECS task definitions. The task override character limit is 8192, Is there any way that we can increase it ? Is there any parameter that I can set in Cloudformation ?.

I am passing on some parameters in a json format with is bigger then the defined limit. Is there any other way I can pass on this json ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to increase it. Perhaps you need to save your parameters/settings somewhere else like DynamoDB, S3, SSM Parameter Store, etc. and pass a reference to that in your task override.